# Is Firebase using IDFA for deeplinking?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using the following Firebase libraries:

- Firebase/Analytics
- Firebase/DynamicLinks
- Firebase/Crashlytics

I don't see in code anything about IDFA or AdSupport framework and my app has been successfully reviewed by Apple with saying that we are not using IDFA. So my question is - will we have some problems after Apple forbids using of IDFA for 3-rd party libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct - you can use Firebase Dynamic Links without IDFA or the AdSupport framework as there is no hard dependency between the two. Note that Google Analytics does use IDFA, but can also work without it enabled.